# Get the arguments from a command line in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, command-line

Is it possible to return the arguments from the `processPath` in this example?
This might make more sense, sorry.

```
Dim processName As String

Dim processPath As String

If processName = "cmd" Then
    Dim arguments As String() = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
    Console.WriteLine("GetCommandLineArgs: {0}", String.Join(", ", arguments))
End If
```

Comment: Are you asking [how to get command line arguments for some other already running process](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/11/25/9928372.aspx)?

Comment: Yes, exactly!  I tried to read the link you provided, I didn't quite understand it though.  I will read it some more.  Thank you.

Comment: The link explains you why you should not be doing it in the first place. If you must, however, you can run the WMI query provided with the [.NET WMI tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms257340.aspx).

Comment: I see, I will read it again.  Actually, it is not a different process, it is the same process.  Does that make a difference?  Basically, if cmd is detected, I would like to get the path and arguments, not something like  c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe.

Answer (score 7):

A simple (and clean) way to accomplish this would be to just modify your `Sub Main` as follows,

```
Sub Main(args As String())
   ' CMD Arguments are contained in the args variable
   Console.WriteLine("GetCommandLineArgs: {0}", String.Join(", ", args))
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you.  But does this work for:

(ByRef currentProcessList() As Process)?

Answer (score 3):

The VB.Net solution to your problem is to use `Command()` VB.Net function when you search to display command's line of currently executed process.

```
Sub Main(args As String())
     Dim sCmdLine As String = Environment.CommandLine()
     Console.WriteLine("CommandLine: " & sCmdLine)
     Dim iPos = sCmdLine.IndexOf("""", 2)
     Dim sCmdLineArgs = sCmdLine.Substring(iPos + 1).Trim()
     Console.WriteLine("CommandLine.Arguments: " & sCmdLineArgs)
End Sub
```

The first outpout will display the complete command's line with name of program.

The second output will display only the command's line without program's name.

Using `args` is C/C++/C#/Java technic.

Using `CommandLine()` function is pure VB and is more intuitive because is return command's line as typed by user without supposing that arguments are type without blank.

Example:

```
LIST-LINE 1-12, WHERE=(20-24='TYPES'),to-area=4
LIST-LINE 1 - 12, WHERE = ( 20-24 = 'TYPES' ) , to-area = 4
```

In this command's syntax, arguments are separated by COMMA and not by spaces.

In this case, it is better to not use `args` technic that is more linked to C and Unix where command syntax accepts arguments separated by space !

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```
Sub WhatEver()
    Dim strArg() as string
    strArg = Command().Split(" ")
    ' strArg(0) is first argument and so on
    '
    '
End Sub
```

Comment: No good option to split at " ".
If you call an exe like
xxx.exe /Folder:"My New Folder"
breaking at " " would destroy everything. You must also use the " char to hold parameters together!